# "Surprisingly as it may seem"

Tags: expressions

I've been wondering whether the sentence in question is correct. I've come across this a lot of times even in professional books, but Google changes it into "Surprising as it may seem".

Comment: You're correct. Since the word describes "it," we need an adjective, not an adverb.  "It may seem surprising."  --> "Surprising as it may seem."

Comment: But - since the form with an adverb is so common - is it 'acceptable'?

Comment: @ILoveChess It sounds completely off and awkward to my native-speaking ear. Maybe more acceptable in some other dialect, like British English? Though I doubt it.

Comment: There is a conflation of the modal pragmatic markers 'Surprisingly' and '[As] surprising as it (this) may seem'. The title is unacceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to work this out is by changing the word order of the two alternatives as follows:

> 1. It may seem *surprisingly*

*v.*

> 2. It may seem *surprising*

Obviously, 1 is incorrect — an adjective (describing ‘it’) is required, rather than an adverb. The latter could be used in a construction of the type:

> *Surprisingly*, he did exactly the opposite to what we had envisaged

Although I personally would try to avoid this, if possible, by constructs such as:

> It was surprsing that…

or

> We were surprised that…

However that is style and personal preference, rather than grammar.